# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetlink

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to get a program my coworkers developed up and running on a new VM. The machine had very few utilities on it to begin with (I had to install make and gcc, for example) and I'm running into an error executing the following gcc command in the makefile:

`gcc -g -ggdb -Wall -Wextra  -o <output_name> <files> -lcrypto -lssl -lnetfilter_queue -lnetlink -lpthread`

When I attempt to use make, I get the following message: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetlink`. I have searched everywhere for a solution but nothing has worked. I have no idea what lnetlink is or what it does, as I did not write any of this program. I originally had the same issue with lcrypto, lssl, and lnetfilter_queue but was able to fix lnetlink. Additionally, this exact makefile worked on an older VM running the same OS (Debian) with more software installed so I know the issue is in my machine and not with the gcc command.

I'm happy to answer any additional questions. All advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-lnetlink` tells the linker to link the resulting program with `libnetlink.so` (on Linux). `libnetlink.so` is not available in Debian packages so you should search on the older WM where it came from.

Comment: Great, I'll try that and get back to you.